# How to add stored procedure variables to SSRS 2012 Labels

Tags: ssrs-2012

Very new to SSRS so bear with me...

I created an SSRS report based on a stored procedure and as part of that procedure I calculate a **StartDate** and **EndDate** for my report. I need to use those two dates in the **Title** of the report but those variables are not part of the dataset created from the stored procedure.

How do I add those variables to the Title of the report?

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @ThisDate date;
SET @ThisDate = getdate(); -- Current date

DECLARE @sdate AS int
SELECT @sdate = CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varchar(10), dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, @ThisDate) - 2, 0), 112)) -- Beginning of previous 2 year

DECLARE @edate AS int
SELECT @edate = CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varchar(10), dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, -1, @ThisDate) - 1, -1), 112)) -- Last Day of previous month
```

Want my report to display:

> From @sdate through @edate   ( from 01-01-2014 through 08-31-2016 )

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now, I would add a SELECT line to use in a dataset:

```
SELECT @sdate as START_DATE, @edate AS END_DATE
```

Your expression would have to use a LOOKUP to get the values from the dataset:

="From " & FIRST(Fields!START_DATE.Value, "DataSet1") & " through " & FIRST(Fields!END_DATE.Value, "DataSet1")

HOWEVER, the better way to do what you want is to use SSRS **parameters** to calculate your START_DATE and END_DATE and then use the parameters when you need the start and end dates.

**START_DATE** Parameter -

Date Type: **DATE**

**Available Value** Expression:

```
="01/01/" & (YEAR(TODAY) - 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Hannover! So I decided to follow your second choice and add parameters for Start_Date and End_Date. I'm adding default values and hiding them from the report so they are just being used for the report title. The Start_Date calculation I used on the StoreProc is "SELECT @sdate = CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varchar(10), dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, @ThisDate) - 2, 0), 112))" ...It might be a -3 depending on an IF statement. The calculation on the report is as you suggested (and adding the condition) "=IIf(month(today)=1,"01/01/" & (YEAR(TODAY) - 3) ,"01/01/" & (YEAR(TODAY) - 2))".

Comment: BUT, I'm havong probles with the End_Date calculation which needs to be the last day of the previous month from TODAY. I used this in the StoreProc"SELECT @edate = CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varchar(10), dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, -1, @ThisDate) - 1, -1), 112))" and I'm trying to build this on the report but cant get a conversion to text "=dateadd(DateInterval.month, datediff(DateInterval.month, -1, TODAY) - 1, -1)". End_Date is defines as Text and even if I chage it to type date I get ...can not convert to type 'Date'...

Comment: There is probably an easier way to get the End_Date (Last day of previous month from TODAY) but I cant find it :-(

Comment: If you use **Specify Values** for the **Default Value** of the **Parameter**, you can use the expression: `=TODAY.AddDays(0 - TODAY.Day)` for the last day of the previous month. It takes TODAYs date and subtracts the day number of the month - September 0th = August 31st.